# IFERROR MATCH formula not searching whole sheet

Tags: arrays, if-statement, excel-formula, match

We use a sheet to look up information. There are 936 rows and will get more as time goes on, however the query returns a blank result (as it should) after row 600, how do i change what the search/lookup area so it will search the whole table on a separate sheet and return the results?

`=IFERROR(IF($D$5=""," ",INDEX(allvehicles2,(MATCH($D$5,indexes2,0)),7))," ")`

Tried to alter the selection and even moving to another sheet but would not return the results.

Comment: You're using named ranges in the name manager you can amend the range. It looks as if FILTER might be a better option if you have Microsoft 365

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to, try using **Tables** with the **XLOOKUP** function.
It simplifies the formula and the table will automatically grow as data is added to it.
This ensures that the formula will use all the data.

Make sure that the data you are using to lookup against is continuous.
That is no empty rows or columns.
Ensure that it has headings.
Turn it into a table by selecting it and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.

You can change the name of your table by selecting the data and not the headers.
Then use the **Name box** to change the name.

Then use the **XLOOKUP** function, with the **lookup_array** and **return_array** values each being a column in the table.  If the value is not found, an empty string will be returned.

Formula structure

```
=XLOOKUP(lookup_value, lookup_array, return_array, [if_not_found])
```

Example formula based on the screenshot

```
=XLOOKUP(A2,MyTableName[Key],MyTableName[Value 6],"")
```

[image]